# Get Visual Studio Code snippets scope programmatically using API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can I get the list of the available scopes for snippets?

Is there any native functionality that would control what files to create and where?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Snippets are scoped to *languages* and introduced to VS Code as global or local to a workspace. Languages can be contributed to VS Code by exceptions. Typically by declaring a language in the `package.json`, adding a syntax and snippet files. **Update:**
Here is the [guide how to add a snippet to any language via your extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/snippet-guide). If you follow the guide and add a snippet to the current workspace, you will notice that the file with extension `.code-snippets` gets created under the `.vscode` folder in the workspace. Therefore you can enumerate all such files using the `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` and `fs.readDir` APIs.

```js
    vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders!.forEach(workspaceFolder => {
        const snippetFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(workspaceFolder.uri.fsPath, '.vscode'))
            .filter(el => /\.code-snippets$/.test(el));
    });
```

Similarly, the global snippets get added as `.code-snippets` files into the user profile folder - on Windows it looks like this: `C:\Users\currentUser\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets\*.code-snippets`. Both locations you can scan for `*.code-snippets` files as well as programmatically add such files to those folders.

Here is the documentation [how to add snippets to a scope via a file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_project-snippet-scope). There does not seem to be any public API to enumerate all such snippet files in a programmatic way.

But if you want to retrieve list of the *languages* in the screenshot you posted, use this API:

```js
vscode.languages.getLanguages()
```

It could help if you explained what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to find where a particular snippet is coming from to change it? Do you want to add a snippet to a language in this list? Or to a language that is not on this list?

Comment: I want to add snippet automatically to specific scope. If there is no such native support, then my goal would be to create the same pick list as on the screenshot I provided. 2 problems there I've got by using getLangages are: I couldn't find a way to get description of the scope that is listed between brackets () and other problem is that I do not know how to create splitlng line that separates existing scopes vs default ones

Comment: So for the first ambition, you can read or write the `.code-snippets` files automatically. Or add the snippet to a language using the extension contribution point. I've expanded my answer accordingly. If this still does not help, please try to be more specific by giving an example of what behavior do you want to achieve.